# ascending order custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, query-posts, order

I'm trying to sort a custom post type in ascending order (instead of the default descending). Registering the post type like so:

```
function codex_custom_init() {

  register_post_type(
    'calendar', array(
      'labels' => array('name' => __( 'Calendar' ), 'singular_name' => __( 'Calendar' ) ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'calendar'),
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'order' => 'ASC'
    )
  );                      

}
```

But for some reason `'order' => 'ASC'` isn't working? It's probably something I'm doing wrong, but is there anyway of achieving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't declare the order of the results when you register the post type.

Instead, you do at the time the results are requested. If you're using WP_Query to get the results then you add your orderby and order arguments to the request.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

If you want to change the order of the results on the archive pages such as http://www.yoursite.com/calendar/ then you have to filter the existing query by can using the pre_get_posts filter like so:

```
function wpse_167441_reorder_calendar($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

    if (is_post_type_archive('calendar')) {
      $query->set('orderby', 'date' );
      $query->set('order', 'ASC' );
    }

  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse_167441_reorder_calendar');
```

If you want this to be the case in the admin area too then you can remove the !is_admin check. Be sure to test that you have not effected other post types when you're doing this - that's why the is_post_type_archive condition is in there.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Hope that's what you were after.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: This is just an extension to the other answer

As already mentioned in the other answer, `orderby` and `order` are invalid arguments supplied for [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

You should take your time and work through the link provided above.

I just also want to raise this, you cannot use `calender` as your post type name. It is a [reserved name](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms).You **will** have to rename your custom post type, you can maybe use the plural name, `calenders`. You should read through the list given to make sure that you don't use any of those names as taxonomy or post type names